# using library without 'require' when using CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, chart.js, cdn

I want to use this [Chart JS reactJs wrapper library](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs).

I am consuming the [library from a CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-chartjs) as I have not set up any module bundling process for this project. I know I could, but was wondering how to use this library without using `require`. I think it would be useful for an answer to explain how to do this for people who are still a bit uncomfortable with some of the newer js practices.

In the react wrapper Chart JS example you will see that it shows:

```
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <LineChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});
```

Without `require` is there anyway to assign the same value to `LineChart` when using a CDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at the file the CDN provides and find out for yourself.

It has this form:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    // Do some stuff to detect the environment
    // When everything fails, just assign a global variable:

    root["react-chartjs"] = factory(root["React"], root["ReactDOM"], root["Chart"]);


})(this, function ( ... ) {
    ....
});
```

Where `root` is the global object (`window` in the browser) and `factory` is just a function that takes the dependencies and returns the library.

To get `LineChart`:

```
window['react-chartjs'].Line
```

Keep in mind `factory` needs `React`, `ReactDOM` and `Chart`. And assumes all these will be in a global variable named the same way.

Comment: nice @marco thanks for that! I am also consuming `ChartJs` from a CDN. Does this mean I will have to change the setup?

Comment: Not at all, as long as you load `ChartJs` before this file and `ChartJs` is stored in a global variable named `Chart`, look at the parameters `factory` takes

Comment: works fine, BTW, can we just call it by sth like `ReactCharJs` just the same as we can use `React` when loading react by CDN